# Changed port of ubuntu ruby on rails server and now i cant connect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu

I changed the port of my ubuntu ruby on rails server and now I can't connect. I get the following message:

`ssh: connect to host (ip port) Connection timed out.`

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If you already re-started SSH on the Ubuntu box, to pick up the service on the new port, then from the client specify the port you would like to connect to as such.. ssh -p  user@host